# Glitching whilst using CSS transitions/translate on iPad when scrolling the page

Tags: css, ipad, webkit, css-transitions, css-transforms

I've noticed whilst optimising animations for use on iPad using hardware acceleration, I seem to be coming across an issue that I haven't fully been able to resolve. If you are applying webkit transforms such as translate, although the animation runs great, if in the middle of an animation occuring the user scrolls the page, when they release it causes the animation to stutter whereby it reverts to its original position and attempts to continue its animation to it's end point.

I've been looking everywhere for resolve on this issue, having seen it occur on the iPad store as well! If you have an iPad at hand and you navigate to, for example: http://webkit.org/demos/transitions-and-transforms/ , if you select an item then before the button animation has completed drag the page(scroll) then release it, you will see the animation flicker back to its original position and then repeat until its complete.

The only way I've been able to work around this is when a touchmove event occurs, I tell the animation to just stay where at its original location, which stops it from trying to repeat the transition on release, as even attempts to just tell it where to go again cause it to revert regardless (seeing as how css transitions seem not technically able to be stopped).

Has anyone found any workarounds to this issue, I'm pretty sure this is a bug on iPad as opposed to a problem with the animation (this does not involve issues regarding preserve-3d and what have you), or if I should be reporting this as an issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm reading between the lines, but I suspect you might see better results if you use touchend versus touchmove or touchstart.